# Hermite Differential Equation - Non-integer values of $\lambda$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, hermite-polynomials

The Hermite differential equation, given by :
$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - 2x \frac{dy}{dx} + \lambda y = 0 $$
has solutions of the 
$$ y(x) = \mathcal{H_n(x)} $$ when $ \lambda \: \epsilon \:\mathcal{Z_+} $

Are there solutions to this equation for a more general case, where $ \lambda  $ is a real number ? More importantly are there convergent solutions for cases where  $ \lambda  $  is not integer.

Comment: I fixed the typo in the equation.

Comment: Thanks for the correction !!

Comment: You welcome ! Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermiteDifferentialEquation.html

The general solution of this equation is
$$c_1 H_{\frac{\lambda }{2}}(x)+c_2 \, _1F_1\left(-\frac{\lambda
   }{4};\frac{1}{2};x^2\right)$$

Comment: Are these solutions square-integrable ?

Comment: It is the first time I have to consider this aspect of the problem. They are not square-integrable.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. I wanted that for a system in quantum mechanics. THE HARMONIC OSCILLATOR

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, I was a quantum physicist loooong time ago. Cheers.

Comment: Oh great ! Then please have a look at this - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96413/harmonic-oscillator-energy-quantisation

Comment: I said : looooooooooong time ago ! You posted a good question at PSE. Cheers

Comment: Oh I see, thanks anyways !! :)

Comment: You welcome, colleague !